# What is the maximum current a 13Amp twin wall socket can handle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

In my country (Ghana, West Africa; however we do follow the UK regulations) a domestic wall receptacle is rated for 13 Amps. If I had a twin wall receptacle rated 13 Amps does it mean that both outlets can handle 13 Amps or the combined amperage of the outlets add up to 13 Amps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your country is the UK, this is a bit variable, they are all good for a total of more then 13A, but how much more....

Most common 13A double sockets are good to about 20A total across the pair, the exception being the MK stuff which is capable of the full 26A.

Check the datasheet for your chosen part to confirm, but IIRC only the MK ones (and possibly only the MK Metalcad ones at that) are specified to the full 26A.